# Auto-reformatting rows based on number of QML Elements

Tags: row, element, qml, qt-creator, rectangles

I am trying to design a UI in which there will be a row of rectangular elements. I need some way to determine how many elements are in the row and if this number exceeds 5, to create a new row. I would just hard code it, but the problem is that it's future customers who will potentially be adding rectangles to the row and I want their only job to be adding the rectangles and not having to worry about creating new rows, etc. Is there a straightforward way to do this with QML? Or even some way to determine the number of elements within a row?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the most straight method is implement ListModel for each row, and ListModel for rows container. Inner ListModel would look like:

```
ListView {
        id: pl_listView
        width: some_width
        height: some_height
        delegate: inner_delegate
        model: id_listModel
        spacing: 2

        ListModel {
            id :id_listModel
            objectName: "ListModel"
        }

        Component {
            id: inner_delegate
            Rectangle {
                color: set_rect_color
                width: set_rect_width
                height: set_rect_height
            }
        }
    }
```

You can simply add objects to model and control, how many delegates it already contains. Then you can perform your 'row' as component, and use it as delegate in outer ListModel (to handle rows). Handle it manually is not a good idea :)